# Calculating the expected profit with Probability A level maths CIE

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

Company sets up display of 20 fireworks! for each firework, the probability that it fails is 0.05,independently of other fireworks

the probability that more than 1 firework fails is 0.264
 the 20 firework cost company  24 dollars each .450 pay the company 10 dollars each to watch the display.if more than 1 firework fails to work, they get their money back.

Calculate the expected Profit of the company.?

Answer given to me is 2830 dollars [2832]

Hint: -480+4500(1-0264)

Please help me with why they multiplied 4500 with (1-0.264)

I've exams tomorrow and i will be so thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If the probability (call it $P(X \ge 1)$) that more than $1$ firework fails, what is $1-P(X \ge 1)$ going to give you? Keeping in mind that $1$ is the probability of the sample space.

Comment: That was exactly my question. any help is appreciated..

Comment: Since $1-P(X\ge1)$ is the probability of the complement, it equals $P(X = 0)$.

Comment: that means the probability stating that no fireworks would fail??

Comment: Yep. The complement of the probability that at least one will fail is the probability that none will fail, since that's the only other event that can happen.